# How to route SP3423?

Tags: pcb-design, routing

maybe is a very simply question but I would like to know how I should route this component. This component is a ESD Protection for USB, and I should route as symetrical as I could, but with this pinout and footprint, How I should to route? Put the traces under NC's pins?

Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the datasheet from where you copy-pasted those two pictures, next to them is the example PCB picture which basically verifies your guess how to wire it.

Yes, route the traces via NC pins.

Comment: I see "*Package isshown astransparent" and I didn't know what it means that. Thabk you so much!